# AWS Quicksight runningSum groupby Client

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I want to create a bar chart that shows the the cumulative total of users in our platform and the break down of this by client over time.

e.g.

Basically something like this:

[image]

I can create a cumulative using a calculated field

```
runningSum(distinct_count({id[user]}),[{created_at} ASC])
```

[image]

Any ideas on how I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a 3 option on the running sum function for this:

runningSum(sum({count}), [truncDate("MM",{creationdate}) ASC], [{region}])